# How to plot map and data with respect to zipcodes/neighbourhoods for amsterdam

Tags: r, highcharts, choropleth

As there is a library dedicated to US zipcodes called as `library(choroplethrZip)` is there any other library for plotting zipcodes in Amsterdam?

I also tried using hcmaps to plot the neighbourhoods but I was not able to find deep.

```
mapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("countries/nl/nl-nh-all"))
```

I can only go till north holland but not deep into Amsterdam.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the whole Highcharts map collection here: https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/
Probably there is no such deep map displaying zipcodes in Amsterdam, so you should create a custom one which is not easy (especially integrating it in R, I have never seen this before). I hope this answer clarifies you a little.

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/create-custom-maps-for-highmaps
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps

Comment: Yes. Creating a map looks difficult. But thank you for the suggestions.